# Peek into a column value in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Using Java for Spark structured streaming (<=2.3), Is there a way to peek into column values without affecting the stream?

The stream is continuously read from a source (kafka) and written to a sink (hdfs).

Use case (1) Log a particular column value as string
Use case (2) With schemaId in column A, I would like to parse string in column B to a JSON -

I tried.

- from_json function needs the schema as String and col("A") couldn't
  be used
- UDF returns a column
- collect() seems to be a terminal operation

Comment: can you post schema of your stream data & excepted output ??